# Can't find bootstrap file in Angular app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an Angular on Rails app following a tutorial.

I'm having problem with front-end dependencies in Rails project.
I installed `bower` and `sprockets` to install the dependencies like following:

```
bower install angular angular-ui-router bootstrap --save
```

This should install bootstrap and other files. 
However, I get an rails error page saying:

> couldn't find file 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap' with type 'text/css'

Here is `application.css` file:

```
 *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Here is `applicatiin.js` file:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require_tree .
```

`.bowerrc` file at `vendor/assets/bower_components`:

```
{
  "directory":"vendor/assets/bower_components"
}
```

Why isn't bower installing dependencies correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @7urkm3n, not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Bootstrap with Bower several times and I can walk you through the setup if that helps using the `bower-rails` gem.

- In your `Gemfile` include `gem 'bower-rails'`
- `bundle install`
- In your `Bowerfile` include `asset 'bootstrap'`
- `bundle exec rake bower:install`
- In your `application.css` include `*= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap`

Restart your server and refresh the page and you should be good to go. Also in your `.bowerrc` file check and make sure your `"directory"` is using the correct path.

Comment: Is there other way installing bower but not using Gemfile? I read that using Gemfile will make another dependency and can cause a problem later. It says over here(https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#jumping-in-with-angular) Search for "There's also a bower-rails" in provided website.

Comment: Were you able to fix this yet? I just went through that part of the tutorial and no errors came up on my end for the setup. Did any errors come up when you used `bower init` or `bower install angular angular-ui-router bootstrap --save` ?

Comment: Neither actually. All those files are made correctly in rails app. But my rails app does not find those bootstrap files when they exist in rails app. `ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap' with type 'text/css'):`. Not sure why path is causing an error. Do you think I should start a new rails project?

Comment: Try a new project and see if that still happens. I also assume that you have restarted your server?

Comment: There was a routing error. I don't know why but bower_component file was made in a weird place so my Rails app wasn't picking it up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same issue - restarting the server solved it:

1. Stop WEBrick
2. `rails s`
3. refresh the page